# Help with interesting sum involving Euler's constant

Tags: sequences-and-series, euler-mascheroni-constant

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant#Integrals) gives an interesting infinite sum for Euler's constant $\gamma$ and I was wondering how one would evaluate this interesting sum.  The sum is given as follows:

Let $N_0 (x)$ and $N_1 (x)$ represent the number of zeros (OEIS [A023416](http://oeis.org/A023416)) and ones (OEIS [A000120](http://oeis.org/A000120)) respectively of the binary expansion of $n$.

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{N_1(n) + N_0(n)}{2n(2n+1)} = \gamma
$$

Comment: See [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.NT/0508042) and [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0512399).

Comment: The numerator of the summand is simply the total number of digits in the binary expansion of $n$, which is $ \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor +1 $ so the problem can be changed to showing that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{  \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor }{2n (2n+1)} = \gamma + \log 2 -1.$$

Comment: To add to @Ragib, there is the following series, due to Vacca: $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{\lfloor\log_2 k\rfloor}{k}$$

Comment: On the linked Wikipedia page it also states Nielsen (1897) found $$\gamma= 1- \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} (-1)^k  \frac{  \lfloor \log_2 k \rfloor }{k+1} .$$ Another way to write $\lfloor \log_2 k \rfloor +1$ is $\lfloor \log_2 2k \rfloor $ so our series could also be viewed as $$\gamma = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{ \lfloor \log_2 2k \rfloor  }{ 2k (2k+1) }.$$ This series appears to be related to the even terms of the sum of Vacca's and Nielsen's series.